# iPhone and iPad App Real and Virtual Memory usage

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, memory

I've been trying to keep my iOS Apps memory footprint nice and low, however, I'm not really sure what a good threshold is for either real or virtual memory is iOS.

At the moment a very simple app is using 12MB real memory and 70MB virtual memory but this is going to increase as my app becomes more complex.

My question is, what are the real and virtual memory levels that I should try to keep below to avoid getting memory warnings?

I realise that this is not an exact science as there are other factors like the memory footprint of other apps on the system but a rough answer would be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed not at all an exact science. In my experience it's at least as important to release enough memory immediately when receiving an OS request to do so as it is to keep memory low.

That being said, as long as I keep my apps under ~80 MB real memory on an iPad I typically don't get any warnings (for refernce, iPad 1 has 256MB). (keep in mind, this is the full memory used, including screen buffers etc. allocated by the OS for your app, not just what you allocated yourself)

Comment: Thanks for your answer - but how about the Virtual Memory levels?

Comment: @NickKuh There is no virtual memory on iOS devices, nothing is every swapped out. (hence the low memory warnings)

Comment: @Pieter Hm, the "Memory Monitor" Instrument refers to Virtual Memory.  What then would it be talking about?

Comment: @MattMc maybe I should phrase it more accurately, there is a virtual address space but there is never paging done to disk. (with regard to Nicks question "what a good threshold is for either real or virtual memory is iOS" I wanted to make clear that the threshold is the same, there is no paging done)